# linux ethernet drivers product id, device id and address

Tags: python, linux, bash, awk, ethernet

On a linux platform, I need to find the product_id, vendor_id and address of an interface given its name from cli. I am using the following commands to find it:

```
# to find addr:
pci_interface_addr0=$(ethtool -i $eth0 | grep -i bus-info | tail -c 8)

# to find ids:
complete_id=$(lspci -nvv | grep $pci_interface_addr0 | awk '{print $3}')
vendor_id=$(echo $complete_id | cut -d \: -f 1)
product_id=$(echo $complete_id | cut -d \: -f 2)
```

Is there is a better approach to this? Since i have hard coded values like tail -c 8 above.

Can this be done in python? As the parent program is mostly a python module.

Appreciate any good inputs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there is a better approach to this?

I would take advantage of the `sysfs` filesystem typically located in `/sys`.  For example, given an interface name `enp0s25` on my system, I can find the vendor in:

```
$ cat /sys/class/net/enp0s25/device/vendor
0x8086
```

And the product id in:

```
$ cat /sys/class/net/enp0s25/device/device 
0x1502
```

The `uevent` file in the same directory contains this information in a form that can easily be sourced into a shell script:

```
$ cat /sys/class/net/enp0s25/device/uevent
DRIVER=e1000e
PCI_CLASS=20000
PCI_ID=8086:1502
PCI_SUBSYS_ID=17AA:21F3
PCI_SLOT_NAME=0000:00:19.0
MODALIAS=pci:v00008086d00001502sv000017AAsd000021F3bc02sc00i00
```

Comment: Thanks @larsks! Much cleaner approach

Comment: I'm glad it helped.  You may want to take a moment and click the checkmark to the left of this answer; that's both a way of saying "thanks" and a way of letting other people know that your question has been answered.